# Coral Dev Board Mini - Cannot connect through USB but device is listed [Windows]

Tags: ssh, connection, google-coral, mendel-os

I successfully flashed a new coral dev board and verified everything went well using the HDMI video feed.  I installed MDT on Windows 10 and can see the device

```
$ mdt devices
jumbo-wasp              (192.168.101.2)
```

But when I try to connect I get a socket error

```
$ mdt shell
Waiting for a device...
Connecting to jumbo-wasp at 192.168.101.2
Couldn't establish ssh connection to device: socket error: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I've also tried to connect using the serial cable (micro USB) following the directions here: https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/serial-console/#connect-with-linux
but the device never showed up in my COM adapters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I am able to use the serial connection now with Putty to connect now (had a bad micro USB cable), but I'm not sure what to do next to get the USB-C connection working with MDT

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this.  The issue was with the Git Bash app they suggested using.  Instead I used a Python Terminal and was able to connect.

Note, when trying to adjust the network adapter settings, nmtui would not work, I instead had to use the command line interface nmcli.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the mdt devices command could not see my Coral Dev Mini.  Git Bash just didn't work at all for me.  Eventually I installed the free Ubuntu terminal for Windows 10 and it worked fine.  I downloaded it directly from Microsoft